# R Code to eliminate not common columns

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two tables T5,T6 where both tables have various columns as humid, temp, dep_delay as from nycflights13 package in R. Now i want to merge T5 and T6 where

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

T1 <- left_join(flights,select(airports,c(1,5)),by=c('origin'='faa'))
T2 <- left_join(T1,select(planes,-c(5,8)),by='tailnum')
T3 <- left_join(T2,select(weather,-c(9,13,15)),by=c("origin"= 'origin','year.x'='year','month'='month','day'='day','hour'='hour'))
T4 <- (subset(T3,arr_delay>0))
T5 <- na.omit(T4)
T6 <- na.omit(T3)
```

These are the tables and I want T5$humid and T6$humid to be merged and to have new table for T6$humid same no of observations as T5$humid. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `dplyr` you can do this in a single chain.  The key to what you want to get is the `anti_join` at the end and the purposeful use of the `.` in the `filter` condition as the y in the `anti_join`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

T6 <- flights %>% 
  left_join(select(airports,c(1,5)), by=c('origin'='faa')) %>% 
  left_join(select(planes, -c(5,8)), by = "tailnum") %>% 
  left_join(select(weather, -c(9,13,15)), by=c("origin"= 'origin','year.x'='year','month'='month','day'='day','hour'='hour')) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  anti_join(filter(., arr_delay >0)) %>%
  select(humid)
```

If this isn't exactly what you want, as it was difficult to determine from your question, let me know.

Comment: Any particular reason or feedback associated with the downvote?

Comment: Don'cha' just love it when some wiseass comes along and drops a downvote with no explanation? I suspect it is the questioner in many such instances and they are using to to signal that the answer wasn't to their liking. But in that instance it really means the question wasn't clear.